# How to draw multiple levels groupby histograms in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like this,

```
col1    col2     col3    
A       east        5      
A       west        7
A       east        1
A       east        6
B       east        2
B       west        9
B       east        8
...
Z       west        4
```

I know how to groupby and made histogram by using

```
df[df.col1.isin(ix)].groupby('col1').hist()
```

How can I get a 2 levels groupby and draw histograms by using the dataframe above?
For each `col1` group histogram I want them in a separate plot. But for each `col2` group. I hope them in one like this.
 [image]

For example, the final results will be 26 histograms from `A-Z`. Each inside has 2 plots(`east&west`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/):

- [`pandas.DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) on `col1` will also order the plot sequence from `A` to `Z`

#### Data:

```py
import string
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

alpha_list = [random.choice(list(string.ascii_uppercase)) for _ in range(10_000)]
coor_list = [random.choice(['east', 'west']) for _ in range(10_000)]
rand_val = [np.random.randint(10) for _ in range(10_000)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': alpha_list, 'col2': coor_list, 'col3': rand_val})
df.sort_values(by='col1', inplace=True)

col1  col2  col3
   A  west     1
   A  east     3
   A  west     9
   A  west     5
   A  west     7
   A  east     1
   A  east     5
   A  west     2
   A  east     2
   A  west     2
```

### Plot:

- Use `sns.displot`

```py
g = sns.displot(data=df, x='col3', col='col1', hue='col2', col_wrap=7, edgecolor='black', bins=range(0, 11, 1), kde=False)
g.set(xlabel='Value Range', ylabel='Frequency')
```

[image]

---

#### `displot` is replace with the figure-level function `displot`

- Select the number displayed per row with `col_wrap`
- [Building structured multi-plot grids](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html)
- [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html)
- [`seaborn.distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html)

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='col1', hue='col2', col_wrap=7)
g.map(sns.distplot, 'col3', hist_kws=dict(edgecolor='black'), bins=range(0, 11, 1), kde=False)
plt.xlabel('Value Range')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.legend()
plt.xticks(range(1, 11, 1))
plt.show()
```

[image]

- if you want tick labels on each graph, put the following code on the line before `plt.show()`:

```py
for ax in g.axes.flatten():
    ax.tick_params(labelbottom=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pivot the table and groupby plot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.random.choice(('A','B'), size=100),
                   'col2': np.random.choice(('east', 'west'), size=100),
                   'col3': np.random.randint(0,10, 100)})

df['idx'] = df.groupby('col1').col2.cumcount()

(df.pivot_table(index=['idx','col1'], 
                columns=['col2'], 
                values='col3')
   .groupby('col1').plot.hist(subplots=False, alpha=0.5)

)
```

Output:

[image]
[image]