# Creating matplotlib graphs using for loops

Tags: matplotlib

I have a list:

`('Amazon': 'AAZ'), ('Apple' : 'AAPL')...` about 34 rows.

I also have a numpy array,

Company : `Amazon  -->  Change : -380.2393913269043`

Company : `American Express  -->  Change : 17.102252960205078`

Company : `Boeing  -->  Change : 34.740291595458984`

Which is about 34 x 3524

My intention is to plot graphs for all the 34 companies, using their name, 'Amazon', and their price 'Change' on a 7 row, 2 column grid

I tried this code:

```
For i in range(0, len(companies)):
    plt.figure(figsize = (12,12))
    ax = plt.subplot(7,2,i)
    plt.plot(movements[i][:])
    plt.title(companies[i])
    plt.show()
```

My output either doesn't print, when putting "i" on the subplot command, or prints in one single column when I put any number.

How to solve this problem?

The output I want is something like this: 
[image: Desired matplotlib output]

Comment: You may want to use something along the lines of `seaborn.FacetGrid`, as in the solution to [How to draw multiple levels groupby histograms in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188627/how-to-draw-multiple-levels-groupby-histograms-in-python/58189722#58189722).  This question is about histograms, but `FacetGrid` words with many types of desired plots.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
plt.figure(figsize = (12,12))

graphs = 1

for i in range(0, len(companies)): 
    plt.subplot(310+graphs) 
    plt.plot(movements[i][:])
    plt.title(companies[i])
    graphs  += 1

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. The above code prints only 3 plots, with this error, "ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 3, not 4"